# Custom Sort Algorithm for changing item ordinance

Tags: c#, algorithm, design-patterns

You see it everywhere, drag and drop an item to a different row or the up and down arrow for moving an item up the list or down the list.

What's a preferred algorithm or pattern for accomplishing this

Comment: `Item.Remove(currentPosition) then Item.Insert(NewPosition)` I guess...

Comment: Give a conrete example, what you're asking about...

Comment: Not a lot to go on here...  doesn't mention what the UI is.  Moving items in a list is easy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Um, have it in an ordered list instead of sorting it?

Say you have a list of items:

```
List<string> l = new List<string>() {"one", "five", "two", "three", "four", "six"};
```

Want to move item 1 (`"five"`) to index 5 (before `"six"`)?

```
l.Insert(5, l[1]);
l.RemoveAt(1);
```

It's not hard to adapt this to any kind of display.

Comment: Note for future users: this doesn't work if the data structure refuses to allow the same object to exists in it twice (as in many UI structures [ListView.Items, for instances]), it also doesn't correctly allow you to move an item *up* the list as the original item's ordinality will have changed.  Try inserting a 'temp' value of some sort where you want the original and then removing by object identity, *then* inserting, and finally removing the temp value.

Comment: @Cpfohl: In that case, just swap the remove and insert operations.

Comment: Very true, but (for example) adding and removing `ListViewItem`s that way still wouldn't work because of the restriction on adding the same item twice.  I wasn't trying to suggest your way wasn't correct, just trying to give people who reach this page in the future a hand.

Comment: @Cpfohl: If you remove the item before adding it, it won't exist twice in the `ListView`. At least, I think not :P

Comment: Right, but then the indexing gets screwed up.  If you remove an item, all indexes downstream from it change, so the algorithm doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Usually, List<>.RemoveAt(), List<>.Insert() are enough to handle this.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the question is not only about how to implement the moving itself but also what to do with near item in the list.

If the list is ordered every item should have its own number in the list. So the common algorithm is the following:

Up:
1. remember the id of the previous item like

```
int id = items[number - 1]; //number is the number of the selected item
```

1. remember the number of the selected item

   int num = current_item.number;
2. current_item.number--;
3. change the number of the previous item:
   get it by id:

   prev = context.where(i => i.id == id),

then change `prev.number = num`

The same for the moving down but the number should be increased.

Or, if you use the list without any ids you need to keep the value of the previous item in the temp variable (or number).